# Como obtener el mod de un valor tipo BigInteger en C#

Tags: c#

Como digo en el titulo, la idea es sacar el mod de cualquier número que sea de tipo BigInteger, de momento tengo esto

```
BigInteger a, c, hallar, b = 0;
            a = BigInteger.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a > 34 && a > 0)
            {
                c = a % 35;
            }
// uso el sino, ya que por ejemplo -42 mod 35 es 28 y en c# al usar % me da que es -7.
// aquí intente aplicar el metodo para hallar el mod a valores negativos. 
// ejemplo: (-42 / 35) + 43 = 0.8 y ese 0.8 se multiplica por n que en este caso es 35 y se
// obtiene el mod que es 28
            else
            {
                if (a < 0)
                {          
                    hallar = a / 35;
                    while (hallar < 0) 
                    {
                        b++;
                        hallar += 1;
                    }
                    c = (b + (a / 35)) * 35;
                }
                else 
                {
                    c = a;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Vuelvo a explicar por si acaso, en la parte del método cuando a < 0, el metodo que aplico para obtener a mod n, es (a / n) + (-(a / n)+1) y donde -(a / n) se obtiene el cociente sin decimales, ejemplo si hubiera dado la operación -53.8 quedaria como -53 y por el menos quedaria 53.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esta cuestión tiene numerosos matices. En realidad, hay varias definiciones de la función modulo, que varían principalmente en qué hacer en caso de números negativos.

En C# se tomó la decisión de que `%` lo que devuelve es [el resto de la división](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-). Eric Lippert [lo explica en su blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/12/05/whats-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus/).

Para resolver tu duda, te voy a proponer un código que creo que te puede servir en casi todos los casos, aunque podrían existir algunos en los que no, todo depende de la definición de módulo que se tome (de hecho, hay diferencias entre cada lenguaje de programación). [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1082917/579895) tienes algunas soluciones mas si la que te propongo no te sirve:

```
static BigInteger Mod(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
{
    return a % b < 0 ? b + (a % b) : a % b;
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
BigInteger big = -42;
var resbig = Mod(big,35); //devuelve 28
```

Comment: Gracias, lo hice de otra forma yo, n base y a un número biginteger menor a cero, entonces su mod seria n - ((a % n)*-1), igualmente gracias por su ayuda.